# digikam: reuse edit filter for batch editing

Tags: filters, batch, digikam

I edited a raw photo and applied some filters (so, I can see them in "used filters" tab in image editing window). I would now like to apply the exact filters in a batch editing for multiple files, is that somehow possible?

edit: It looks like this has been [planned](https://www.digikam.org/news/2010-08-18_gsoc_how_is_digikam_s_non-destructive_editing_this_time_with_pictures/):

> In the future I'd like it to be able to dynamically switch any entries
>   on or off to see how would the image look and also to change the used
>   values for particular filters. Basic foundations for this are already
>   layed down. This will later also allows you to take one set of
>   modifications and apply it to any other images.

But this post is from 2010?? Its still not implemented?